# Lenovo Thinkpad fan problem

Tags: thinkpad, fan

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad E420 (1141BRG) (Intel i3-2330M) laptop for 4 years now, and I have a problem with fan controlling and as a consequence overheating problems.

This happens on Linux Mint 17.2Mate-64bit now, and did the same with Ubuntu 14.04 last year. On Windows everything works fine.

I have installed the [thinkfan program](http://sourceforge.net/projects/thinkfan/) and I cannot make use of it through bash commands and, even more, I cannot setup the GUI.

The Psensor program monitors my CPU. I have searched for the compatibility of this laptop with Mint (http://community.linuxmint.com/hardware) but did not find a simillar issue from others...

Any ideas?

Comment: anyone who knows? the problem perists, so ijust reboot the laptop sa as to force the fan run at high speed an the boot with this speed set, into linux mint... strange workaround